# How to extract a msg object which I'm getting from a http request?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I'm still a newbie to this. What I have done is, I've tried sending an `http` request and I'm trying to pass the below response via my custom node.  The msg object which looks like:

```
[
  {
    "userId": 1,
    "deviceId": 2,
    "type": "SM",
    "eventName": "TemparatureChanged",
    "stateName": "update",
    "eventParameters": [
      {
        "name": "temparature",
        "type": "Double",
        "value": 35.01
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

How can I retrieve the *value* from the **eventParameters** array above?

I tried the below in a function node:

```
var data  = msg.eventParameters[0].value;
return data;
```

And I want to only print the above property through the debug node. My debug node contains `msg.payload`, also I tried having it as a complete msg object still no luck.

And in my custom node (**IOT-Input**) `js` file I've got this:

```
this.on('input', function (msg) {
            node.warn("I saw a payload: "+msg.payload);
            // in this example just send it straight on... should process it here really
            node.send(msg);
});
```

My flow looks like this:

[image]

Where am I going wrong? Any help could be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't say where you got your sample msg from at the top of the question but if it can from the `console.log` in your node, then what you have is the `msg.payload` not the `msg`.

So you should be using something like:

```
var data = msg.payload[0].eventParameters[0].value;
```

And also you shouldn't be just returning `data` from the function node, it should be a `msg` object so something like this:

```
var data = msg.payload[0].eventParameters[0].value;
msg.payload = data;
return msg.payload;
```

Comment: Awesome, this works! Just a small typo there in the second line (**msg.payload**).

Answer (score 1):

`msg` is an array so it should be:

```
var data  = msg[0].eventParameters[0].value;
```

Comment: I tried the above, but it gives **"TypeError: Cannot read property 'eventParameters' of undefined"**.  Could it be something wrong with my flow? But then when I just pass the msg, it's actually printing the whole object.

Comment: Yes sure I can. Code snippet of the function node? or my custom node's js?

Comment: Something more than what you wrote.

Comment: This is my [input-node.js](http://pastebin.com/6tPEH3JN) and I don't have nothing more than what I have shown above in my function node.